# A question about soldering iron tips with same tip size

Tags: soldering

I have [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/soldering-iron-tips/0661138) and [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/soldering-iron-tips/1751196) soldering iron tips. They have the same tip size 0.8 mm. Their series are called ETP and ET OL. But they have same tip size. It is just one of them has a longer conical head then the other (34.5 mm  and 43.5 mm.)

What can be the different use cases? Which one is better for surface mount soldering?

Comment: getting between components.

Comment: Do not use conical in most cases. Chisel is almost always better. For surface mount, the best tends to be a 2.4mm-2.7mm bevel/hoof tip that *only* has tinning on the face and *not the sides*. It holds onto the viscous solder bead protruding from the end and keeps it there which lets it wrap around and under components, even ones much smaller than the tip. It's like a T-1000 tip.

Comment: How about the round type(one of the type in question)? In my question not two of them conical. One of them classified as round. See here https://www.techcogroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Weller-ET-tips.pdf So can we say round better than conical and chisel is the best? And which type is good for surface mount?

Comment: The label might say round but that's still conical. There tends to be multiple names for the same shape. Look at the shape, not the name.  Bevel/hoof with only tinning on the faces is best for SMD. I even use it for through-hole because you free up one hand from holding solder wire. Chisel is fine for through-hole though.

Comment: It's quite strange but I have mostly abandoned chisels. I mainly use just one huge 6.6mm chisel for very large work and solder wick. I use a tinned-face only bevel/hoof for SMD and a spoon for through-hole. Spoon is a hoof with a hollow cavity. It's made for SMD but not great at it because the solder bead doesn't protrude enough but it holds lots of solder so you free up the one hand so you can do 3-5 thru-hole joints or so before replenishing the tip. Without the cavity you can only do one or two thru-hole but much better for SMD.

Comment: @DKNguyen "It holds onto the viscous solder bead protruding from the end and keeps it there"  How would that work with flux core solder? I would imagine not at all and you'd have to use external flux?

Comment: @Lundin Yeah you do need external flux but you need that anyways for SMD drag soldering so it's only noticeable if you are using it for thru-hole and freeing up one hand from holding solder wire. You need that free hand for SMD too for tweezers. Not necessary for through-hole but it's nice to have for thru-hole.

Comment: @DKNguyen I always use flux core but apply external flux depending on component type. Usually no need for external flux when doing "large" stuff like 1.27mm standard IC.

Comment: As for freeing up hands: fixtures, tape :)

Comment: @lundin I *HATE* tape and flipping the board like an idiot and taping *just so* so those the component doesn't wobble or tilt yet is stable. It's worse than desoldering. And fixtures are for the PCB so don't retain components to the PCB (I thought everyone used PCB fixtures?)

Comment: The longer one will be slower to deliver heat to the joint being worked on.  This may or may not be an issue (depends on the thermal mass of the target joint).  Generally you want to minimize the thermal resistance while soldering so, when possible, you'd choose the shorter/fatter tip.    Consider, it's not the tip that actually produces the heat.  There's a heater inside the shaft of the pencil.  The tip is connected to it and gets hot by proximity, so heat has to flow through the tip to get to the working point.   Longer tips = longer paths.

Answer (score 5):

The more narrow the tip is, the easier it is to use for SMD/fine-pitch work, but also when modifying existing boards. With wider tips you have a larger risk of bumping into nearby components. On the other hand, wider tips heat quicker and deliver heat faster/better to the joint.

As for which tip to use for what, it's fairly subjective and often boils down to personal preference.

My personal favourite for SMD/fine-pitch is a "bent" tip. The advantage of these over conical is the same as mentioned above: not as easy to touch other components/surfaces by mistake. Conical tips also often force you to hold the iron in awkward angles instead of "like a pen". I never use conical tips nowadays. I suppose they may be useful for very particular kinds of connectors like certain coax/RF ones, but that's about it.

For larger components/through-hole I'd recommend the "chisel"/"screwdriver" type of tips since these are the best when it comes to delivering heat and you can sometimes press the flat side of the tip against the joint for extra heat.

Comment: Conical tips suck. Even when they are the only tip that will do the job (when the tip is super small and narrow...<0.5mm, so can't b made in another way)

Comment: @DKNguyen Ah crap, you are right. I wondered why I had never heard of the term before. I always called these "screwdriver". Will fix, thanks.

Comment: But in my question not two of them conical. One of them classified as round. See here: https://www.techcogroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Weller-ET-tips.pdf So can we say round better than conical and chisel is the best? And which type is good for surface mount?

Comment: @DKNguyen As for super small, I've done down to 0.35mm pitch with a bent tip, as well as 0201 and 0402. Yes these tips don't heat as well as larger ones but what can you do. Also, the width of the solder matters a lot too. I'd use 0.2mm something for small SMD jobs.

Comment: @user1999 Weller might call them something, another manufacturer something else... I'm not sure how standardized these terms are.